# Frobenius method solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method, singular-solution

Suppose I have a second order linear differential equation. I have a solution about a regular singular point say $x=0$. Suppose the indicial equation has a repeated root for the indicial equation. I get the first non trivial solution say $y_1$. Now in order to get the second non trivial linearly independent solution can I just write $y_2= y_1 \log(x)$. Hence the complete solution can be $y= (a+ b\log(x))y_1$. Can this be the final answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y_1 = x^\sigma \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

be the first solution. To obtain the second solution it is always necessary to add a log term if the roots of the indicial equation are repeated (in general, there are two linearly independent series solutions if the roots to the indicial equation $\sigma_1 $ and $\sigma_2$ obey $\sigma_1 - \sigma_2 \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, and one otherwise). The form of the second solution is

$$y_2 = x^\sigma \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n + cy_1\log{x}$$ where $c$ is some nonzero constant. $c$ is not arbitrary, it is fixed by $a_0$ and $b_0$.

The form of $y_2$ can be derived using reduction of order, or you can assume it as the trial solution and substitute into the ODE.

Comment: In $y_2$, the first part will give the same solution which is $y_1$. Isnt it? For repeated root

Comment: No, $b_n$ are different coefficients. You solve the recurrence relations multiple times for differing values of $\sigma$ @Upstart

Comment: We have only one value of $\sigma$ because the root is repeated. What do you mean by different value of $\sigma$

Comment: Whoops, I misspoke sorry. In the case of repeated roots you could have two undetermined coefficients (eg $a_0$ and $a_1$ in the case of a two-step recurrence) which would lead to these pair of solutions.

Comment: I didnt understand you properly.

Comment: Could I just take $cy_1\log(x)$ as the second solution, put this in the differential equation and get the value of $c$. Is this how it should be done?